# Layout of textviews and tablerows in TableLayout - Android

Tags: java, android, textview, tablelayout, tablerow

What I am trying to achieve is a simple 3 column, 11 row table.  Right now all of the data is displayed in 1 column and 33 rows.  Here is the output:

```
Rank
Percentage
Score
1
1234
13453
2
2352435
312413
3
235325
235423

//etc...
```

I have messed around with many online examples of TableLayouts but all my output stays the same for all the examples.  What I have below is just the last one I tried.  Any suggestions?

Highscoresmain.xml

```
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true" >"

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="1" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/rowHeader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rank"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/percentage"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/score"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/r1r"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/r1p"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/r1s"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/r2r"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/r2p"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/r2s"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

       //TableRows 1 through 10 are identical.

        <Button 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="MAIN MENU"
            android:id="@+id/homeBtn" />
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: U have to put three text view between the corresponding table row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it this way for all your rows in the table

```
        <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/rowHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rank"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/percentage"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/score"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        </TableRow>
```

Comment: Oh whoops!  Didn't notice I was closing the ````TableRow```` right away.  Thanks!